# Laravel Lumen change log file name

Tags: lumen

Lumen logs are written to `/storage/logs` and by default given the name `lumen.log`. How do I change the file name to say `xyz.log`?

Comment: The filename [is hardcoded](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/f018f423daba627d577e217100d9db82db9aeb10/src/Application.php#L604) into the framework core. Not sure if it can be overridden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the location and the name of the log file is hardcoded.

Now if for some compelling reason you want to change it you can always extend `Laravel\Lumen\Application` class and override `getMonologHandler()` method.

Create a new file `Application.php` in `app` folder that looks like

```php
namespace App;

use Laravel\Lumen\Application as LumenApplication;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class Application extends LumenApplication
{
    protected function getMonologHandler()
    {
        return (new StreamHandler(storage_path(env('APP_LOG_PATH', 'logs/xyz.log')), Logger::DEBUG))
            ->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
    }
}
```

Now change

```php
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
```

to

```php
$app = new App\Application(
```

in `bootstrap\app.php` file

Voila your log file now is called `xyz.log`. More over you can change it to whatever you want by defining the environment variable `APP_LOG_PATH` i.e. via `.env` file

```
APP_LOG_PATH=logs/abc.log
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. The above works exactly as stated. Happily renaming logs on demand.

Answer (score 5):

There is a public method available `configureMonologUsing` seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/4e8af6b6792a212fd7d405469add56a514f100c0/src/Application.php#L382) and referenced [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/4e8af6b6792a212fd7d405469add56a514f100c0/src/Application.php#L366) that you can use to override the default behavior without extending the Application.

Here's how you would use it in your *bootstrap/app.php*:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(Monolog\Logger $monolog) {

    $handler = (new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(storage_path('/logs/xyz.log')))
        ->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));

    return $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
});
```

*Bonus*: Also checkout monolog's `RotatingFileHandler`.

Comment: Note that if you are using an *absolute* path, you should exclude the `storage_path` function. Otherwise, works as expected.

Comment: `configureMonologUsing` is not available from Lumen 5.6

Answer (score 2):

In lumen 5.6 and above lumen checks for file config\logging.php. If it is present, lumen will configure logging as indicated in this file.

To get the base template, copy the file from vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\config\logging.php to config\logging.php.

Then edit config\logging.php

```
    ...

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/xyz.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
    ],
    ...
```